# How to add a column of counts to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have:

```
TAG | REVIEW
A   | hello
B   | yay
A   | win
```

in an ArrayList and I am trying to get:

```
TAG | COUNT  
A   | 8       //hello+win =8
B   | 3       //yay =3
```

where count is the total number of characters in all strings with the same tag. I have been reading about Collections and Maps, but I am completely lost. Can someone explain how to solve this in pieces?

1) To get the count:

```
List<String,Integer> poll_reviewText_count=new ArrayList<>();
for(String l:poll_reviewText){
    poll_reviewText_count.add({l[0],l[1].length()}) //TAG, COUNT
}
```

2) Then I think I need to combine all the instances of TAG that match into one sum. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: The Java Collections Framework does not have a `List<T, U>` .. it specifies only a `List<E>`.  Your question makes very little sense.

Comment: `List` only takes one generic type parameter, so that wouldn't compile. What's your actual collection type?

Comment: Since you've been reading about the Collections framework, why not use a `Map` implementation for this task? The key will be the tag and the value the count. You'll need to check to see if the tag (key) exists in the `Map`, and if so add it to the existing mapped count, since `Map.put()` will replace a key value pairing. As it's not entirely clear how the data is originally it's difficult to give a definite answer, You say `l` is a `String` but treat it as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such thing as `List<V, T>` in java. Also you can't use a `Map` for your data, because inserting this :

```
TAG | REVIEW
A   | hello
B   | yay
A   | win
```

In map, `A   | hello` will get replaced by `A   | win` (they have the same key).

A solution will be to create a class that will contain `TAG` and `REVIEW` information:

```
class Bar {
    String tag;
    String review;
    // setters - getters
}
```

And then using the java `stream`, you can `collect` the data how you want:

```
Map<String, Integer> collect = poll_reviewText_count.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bar::getTag, Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.getReview().length())));
```